# Colocar imagen sobre mi div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola bunas tardes esto intentando pasar este diseño a html con Bootstrap pero no puedo colocar las imágenes sobre mis divs, tiene alguna idea de como hacer un diseño parecido a mi diseño en photoshop. Hasta el momento esto es lo que tengo.

> Diseño esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Lo que tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Mi Código

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es-MX" xml:lang="es-MX">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">

<title>Seguridad | Abacom</title>

<meta name="description" content="Seguridad">

<link href="http://localhost/Abacom/images/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Abacom/css/stylesheet.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Abacom/css/animate.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Abacom/css/rateYo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/menu/menu.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/landing/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/css/corporate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/aos/aos.css">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LcKW5MUAAAAAFDEbbeidit-Mp68IWpXBXuHtmuZ"></script>

<style>
textarea:required:focus {
    border-color: red;
}
input:required {
    border-color: red;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    .bg-overlay {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)), url("https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339442236-8ceb164046f8?q=75&fm=jpg&s=8eb83df8a744544977722717b1ea4d09");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        color: #fff;
        /*height: 450px;*/
        padding-top: 50px;
        width: 100%
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    .sangria{
        list-style-type: disc;
        list-style-position: inside;
        text-indent: -1em;
        padding-left: 1em;
    }
    .descripcion {
        padding-top: 6%!important;
        /*padding-bottom: 20px;*/
        background-color: #fff;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Preloader - style you can find in spinners.css -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<div class="preloader">
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="loader__figure"></div>
        <p class="loader__label">Abacom</p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Cabeza -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md" id="mainNav">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-6 offset-md-5">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Abacom" style="padding: 0px">
            <img alt="Abacom Telecomunicaciones" src="../assets/images/logo/logo_blue.png" style="width: 200px; height: 30%">
            </img>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- ./Cabeza -->

<!-- Cuerpo -->
<div class="">

<div class="descripcion col-sm-12" style="padding-bottom: 0px">
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Container fluid  -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- Static Slider 4  -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <div class="static-slider4">
                <div class="container" style="background-image:  url(http://localhost/Abacom/assets/images/landing/l8/Fondo.png);">
                    <!-- Row  -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 img-anim" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="3200">
                            <img alt="wrapkit" class="img-fluid" src="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/images/landing/l8/Globo.png" style="height: 50%; width: auto;"/>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Column -->
                        <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto align-self-center" data-aos-duration="1200">
                            <img alt="wrapkit" class="img-fluid" src="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/images/landing/l8/Why.png" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Column -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- End Static Slider 4  -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Feature 2  -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<div class="spacer feature5" style="color: #000">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Row  -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                <h2 class="title font-medium">
                    Porque hoy comenzó a perder dinero . .</br>
                    Le secuestraron su información.
                </h2>
                <!-- <h6>
                    ¿Sabes cuanto le cuesta a tú empresa una interrupción de internet?
                </h6> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row  -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="feature5" style="background-color: #2581c4; color: #fff">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Row  -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                <h2 class="title font-medium">
                    Y tú, ¿Que estás haciendo para</br>
                    proteger los datos de tú compañia?
                </h2>
                <!-- <h6>
                    ¿Sabes cuanto le cuesta a tú empresa una interrupción de internet?
                </h6> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row  -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="feature5" style="color: #000">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Row  -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                <h2 class="title font-medium">
                    Los ladrones evolucionan y ya no necesitan
                    antifaces, ni se conforman con carteras, los ladrones de estos tiempos secuestran tu información y piden un rescate por ella.
                </h2>
                <!-- <h6>
                    ¿Sabes cuanto le cuesta a tú empresa una interrupción de internet?
                </h6> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row  -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- End Feature 2  -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Feature 39  -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Projects Section -->
<section class="projects-section">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Project One Row -->
        <div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters mb-5 mb-lg-0">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 p-5" style="border: 2px solid black;">
                <div class="container" style="color: #000;">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                    <!-- <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-offset-0"> -->
                    <h5>
                        Puede ayudarte a minimizar el riesgo de tú operación a través de la seguridad administrada.
                    </h5>
                    <!-- <h5>
                        Nos especializamos en que tu comunicación funcione al 100% desde el inicio!
                    </h5> -->
                    <!-- </div> -->
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 p-5" style="background-color: #2581c4;">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul>
                        <li style="color: #fff!important">
                            <mark style="color: #fff!important">
                                Protge tus datos.
                            </mark>
                        </li>
                        <li style="color: #fff!important">
                            <mark style="color: #fff!important">
                                Conoce que páginas consultan tus empleados. 
                            </mark>
                        </li>
                        <li style="color: #fff!important">
                            <mark style="color: #fff!important">
                                Bloquea sitios por contenido, usuario y horario. 
                            </mark>
                        </li>
                        <li style="color: #fff!important">
                            <mark style="color: #fff!important">
                                Asegura la continuidad de tu negocio sin preocupaciones y sin interrupciones.
                            </mark>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</div>
<!-- ./Cuerpo -->

<!-- Modales -->
<!-- ./Modales -->

<!-- Archivos JS -->
<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/js/pooper.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/js/abacomjs2.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/js/rateYo.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/menu/menu.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/js/swiper.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/js/custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Abacom/assets/aos/aos.js"></script>
<!-- ./Archivos JS -->
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que intento colocar bien son las imágenes sobre los divs, no importa el footer.

Espero me puedan apoyar

Comment: Quieres colocar todo el diseño como una imagen sola sobre un div? Si es así intenta:   `<div><img src="imagen.jpg"></div>`. Eso es lo único que entendí, tu pregunta no da muchos detalles :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute; 
}

.azul {
  background:blue;
  z-index:1; /*El z-index de la caja azul es menor al de la caja roja*/
}

.rojo {
  background:red;
  z-index:2; /*El z-index es mayor al de la caja azul por lo que se muestra primero que la caja roja*/
  left:100px;
  top:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="azul">Tu fondo</div>
<div class="rojo">Tu imagen</div>
```

puedes agregar la propiedad a tu imagen

```
z-index: 1;
```

z-index nos permite manejar los elementos como si fueran capas permitiéndonos decidir que elemento aparecerá arriba de otro.

Ademas te recomiendo leer acerca del [sistema de grillas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)  para poder ordenar el contenido de tu pagina.

Comment: algún ejemplo que me puedas mandar para guiarme por favor

Comment: https://codepen.io/falconmasters/pen/GEFHc ahi hay un ejemplo simple, imagina que tu imagen es el cuadrado rojo y tu fondo el azul. Agregale z-index para asi estar por encima de tu div, es eso lo que buscas verdad?

Comment: El ejemplo ayudaría más aquí amigo

Comment: @BetaM edite la respuesta y agregue el ejemplo en ella, espero haberlo hecho de manera adecuada, soy nuevo y la verdad que solo buscaba ayudar con ese link, saludos!